# How do I teach my device to talk DeviceNet?

Tags: communication-protocol

My boss is planning to implement DeviceNet on some of our products. I've looked through Google and odva.org but I can't seem to find any specific technical detail which tells me what and how I should do.

Here is my amateur understanding after reading random articles on the Internet. I would appreciate it if someone here can make them clear for me.

1. DeviceNet, or CIP in general, is in fact a **closed** protocol, despite the "open" stereotype in the company name "ODVA". You have to pay for the specification. Is this correct?
2. I can find a lot of "tutorials" about DeviceNet, but I can't really do anything practical without the official DeviceNet specification, right?
3. Is Vendor ID mandatory? If I somehow know how to talk DeviceNet, will the target refuse to talk to me without a valid Vendor ID?
4. I know CAN bus. Once I understand DeviceNet protocol, it's going to be purely coding stuff, right?
5. My company sells UPS monitoring hardware. We are not selling millions but maybe a few hundreds of thousands of devices per year. Is DeviceNet worth it?
6. How many software devs does it take to implement DeviceNet on a finalized product?

Thank you.